# if word found play macro

Tags: if-statement, ms-word, playback, imacros

```
var ret;
while (ret=1) {
   ret = iimPlay("macro.iim");
   if (ret == -921)
      iimPlay("macro2.iim");   
}
```

it works amazing but sometimes the session ends but I don't know exactly how much the session last, do you know if there is a way to login if you are in "specific url" or something like that?

> RuntimeError: element IMG specified by WIDTH:100 was not found, line 20(-921)"

as you can see I'm already using -921 to do another macro but is there any way to do something if that specific tag is not found?

Maybe a new js file can be created and it will be my new "macro2" with something like this "if word is found play macro3 if not play oldmacro2""

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I test for a tag I usually extract some part of it and test the extracted text for "#EANF#".  If the tag is not found you will get the string ["#EANF#"](http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction) and you can route your program to do something else.  Here is an example:

```
var macro, returnCode;

macro="CODE: ";
macro+="URL GOTO=http://www.google.com/\n";
macro+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbqf ATTR=ID:gbqfba EXTRACT=TXT\n";

returnCode = iimPlay(macro);
lastExtract = iimGetLastExtract();

if (lastExtract.localeCompare("#EANF#") !== 0)
{
    alert("Tag Found");
} else 
{
    alert("Tag not found");
}
macro="CODE: ";
macro+="URL GOTO=http://www.google.com/\n";
macro+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:gbf ATTR=ID:gbqfba EXTRACT=TXT\n";

returnCode = iimPlay(macro);
lastExtract = iimGetLastExtract();

if (lastExtract.localeCompare("#EANF#") !== 0)
{
    alert("Tag Found");
} else 
{
    alert("Tag not found");
}
```